# Is there any good way to make a completly automated watermelon/pumpkin farm in vanilla Minecraft without commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have been trying to create a completely automated watermelon/pumpkin farm, mainly with observer blocks. However all of my attempts so far have caused the harvesting to trigger an infinite redstone loop when the observer block detects the piston moving. Is there any good way to make an automated farm without commands that can infinitely harvest melons/pumpkins? (At least until storage runs out.)

Comment: An internet search of "Minecraft pumpkin farm" or "Minecraft melon farm" both yield the official Minecraft wiki "[Tutorials/Pumpkin and melon farming](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Pumpkin_and_melon_farming)" as the very first result.  A page which includes growing mechanics and several designs of manual, semi-automatic, and fully automatic farm types.  Please do research before posting a question.  This is fully covered in the help center page [How do I ask a good question?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you have seen the wiki page and none of those solutions work for you, edit your question to include many more details.  Details to explain what you do need, why those solutions won't work, and what you have attempted already.  Screen shots are always helpful with redstone creations.

Answer (score 1):

First you want to make this or something like it:[image]

Then you'll want to add a lever like this:[image]

After that just use the lever then use it again. After that you'll have a fully automatic farm. Have Fun =D

Comment: This would require you to manually trigger the piston for each melon. I suppose you could hook it up to some kind of long redstone clock though.

Comment: It does not that's why you use it again and that's why on the repeaters the ticks are as far back as they can go. So it goes in a endless loop and the melons fall into the water which leads to a hopper which goes to a chest which the player can get to.

Answer (score 1):

If you wire the circuit without observers to make the melon a conductor, completing the redstone flow, then you can have a piston to crush it then go into a hopper minecart. Voila!

Example: BR R

When the melon grows: BRMR

Then the piston crushes the melon since the circuit is completed.

Key:

B: redstone block

R: repeater

M: melon

Answer (score 0):

```
RR
XX
OP
S
DD
```

R=Redstone dust, X=Solid Block, O=Observer (face pointing down), P=Piston (also facing down), S=Stem (Watermelon or Pumpkin), D=Dirt. This is a sideview, and is tileable.

This works under the premise that the vine itself updates when a watermelon/pumpkin is produced. To make it fully automatic, run a hopper minecart underneath the dirt to suck up drops, and place glass around the front so the drops don't fall somewhere they shouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

you need to have a platform with observers and pistons above a pumpkin patch, with a minecart collection system underneath. this is alot more efficient then using things like water streams.

heres a video on how to make one

Comment: Could you add more details to this? The video is helpful, but our rules say that videos and images can't be the main source of information in an answer.

Comment: its a bit too complex to fit every detail in an arquade comment, but the gist is that you need to have observers looking at the stalks, and then pistons facing the areas surrounding the stalks. you need to have redstone on top of the observers so that the pistons are powered every time the stalk updates, which is whenever a pumpkin/melon will grow. then, have a minecart hopper collection system underneath to pick up all the items. hopefully this helps. and that you for checking out the video

Comment: It is better if you edit this post to provide the information, because comments have a low character limit.

Answer (score -2):

Ok so
Have an observer facing the stalk
have a piston facing the place where it will grow
have the piston next to the observer, horizantal
place a block behing the piston and the observer
put a redstone dust on top of each
voila! just build a hopper collection system and ur golden